# Splash Screen and navigation

Tags: react-native, expo, splash-screen

Firstly, I would say I am new to react native / expo.

I have an app and I would like to enhance the user experience by avoiding some loading state in my app.

I have the following code working but the 2 seconds I am displaying the SplashScreen are kind of pointless because I can't process anything in the meantime.

I would like that during the SplashScreen, the App goes into the right screen: Signedin vs signedout, onboarded vs not, load ProfileView (...) while the splash screen is on and then when the timer goes off, then just open the curtain on the right loaded screen.

Can it work like that?

```js
// Keep the splash screen visible while we fetch resources
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();


const App = () => {
  const [appIsReady, setAppIsReady] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function prepare() {
      try {
        // Pre-load fonts, make any API calls you need to do here
        await useFonts();
        // Artificially delay for two seconds to simulate a slow loading
        // experience. Please remove this if you copy and paste the code!
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
      } catch (e) {
        console.warn(e);
      } finally {
        // Tell the application to render
        setAppIsReady(true);
      }
    }

    prepare();
  }, []);

  const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
    if (appIsReady) {
      // This tells the splash screen to hide immediately! If we call this after
      // `setAppIsReady`, then we may see a blank screen while the app is
      // loading its initial state and rendering its first pixels. So instead,
      // we hide the splash screen once we know the root view has already
      // performed layout.
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [appIsReady]);

  if (!appIsReady) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <ClerkProvider tokenCache={tokenCache} publishableKey={config.clerkPublishableKey}>
      <NavigationContainer onReady={onLayoutRootView}>
        <SignedIn>
          <ProfileImageUriProvider>
            <OnboardedProvider>
              <AppNavigator />
            </OnboardedProvider>
          </ProfileImageUriProvider>
        </SignedIn>
        <SignedOut>
          <AuthNavigator />
        </SignedOut>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </ClerkProvider>
  );
};
```

Comment: what do you mean by "App goes into the right screen"

Answer (score 0):

**Create** NativeStack Navigator

```js
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const AppNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <Stack.Screen name="LandingScreen" component={LandingScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Authentication" component={Authentication} />
      <Stack.Screen name="MainStack" component={MainStack} />
   </Stack.Navigator>


// Loading Screen
export function LandingScreen() {

  useEffect(() => {
    const isLogged = async () => {
     // any condition to check if user is logged in 

    if (user) navigation.replace('MainStack');
     else navigation.replace('Authentication');


    isLogged();
  }, [navigation]);

  return (
    <View>
        <ActivityIndicator />
    </View>
  )
}
```

**Now**,
`MainStack` & `Authentication` can be stacked with multiple screens.

```js
const AuthenticationStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
```

*(Authentication stack can include screens like sign in, sign up, forget password, etc)*